# Alternative to file_get_contents() for theme operations

Tags: theme-development, filesystem

My theme options page needs to write to the style.css file in order to store updated theme settings. To do that, I'm using file_get_contents() and file_put_contents()

However, theme-check plugin complains about it. What is an acceptable alternative for writing to local files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, but adequate I think.

While I have not tested this, I doubt that there would be a problem if you used the [Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) provided by the Core.